# How do I set CSS Modules on React?

Tags: reactjs, react-css-modules

I want to set `css-modules` for the first time on a `React` study project.

I have learned that on `react-app +2` I do not need to `eject` in order to get `css-modules` running. I have tried learning the process in [this link](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/01/create-react-app-v2.html) with no success, as the [css-modules set up](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet) have disappeared from the docs.

I have created a `react` project using webstorm. I cannot locate my webpack.config.js file as well.

Could anymore please explain how do I make this work on my project please?

I have tried the following:

**App.js file**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import classes from './App.css';
import UserOutput from './Components/UserOutput/userOutput'

//...code in between

 return (
            <div className={classes.App}> //I have tested this, but it does not work
                <h1>This is a ReactJs exercise App!</h1>
                <h2 className={assignedClasses.join(' ')}>Cool Cards are being displayed below</h2>
                {types}
                <br/>
                <button className={btnClasses.join(' ')} onClick={this.hideComponentHandler}>V-if in React</button>
            </div>
        )
```

**App.css file**

```
.App {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/ (in short, add `.module.css` to specify a css module import -- without `.module`, it'll just be a global css import).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the filename from App.css to App.module.css